# Comparing several complex lists in Java

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, list

I am currently making a program for the Android platform but I need some help, I am pretty new to Java/Eclipse. Here's the deal:
One of the features that the program will have is allowing you to select items from a list that are sorted in groups (groups form a list of their own (a list in a list if you put it like that)) and the program needs to make a list out of those items that you have selected. Then the program needs to compare that list with one or more lists of the same sort and see which items are matching and make yet another list of those matching items. Now, since I am really new into programming with Java and the SDK can anyone help me get an idea of the best way to do this? There needs to be a LOT of items in the starting lists (more than 500), so should I put them in some sort of a database? Also, the same item can be in several groups, but it needs to be the SAME item (if I check one in the first group it needs to be checked in the second group too).

Thanks in advance and since this is my first time posting sorry if I did anything wrong! :)

P.S. English is not my native language, but I hope I explained my problem good enough :)

Edit: Whoops! Just noticed that I made a mistake with my numbers. Not "more than 500", rather more than a few thousand, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

- 500 items is not a LOT - it is actually a few ;-)
- the `List` interface contains several methods that can help you, such as [retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29): if you write `list1.retainAll(list2);`, list1 will contain all the items that were both in list1 and list2 before the call.

To get a more specific answer, you will need to provide some code that shows what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am still learning the language, so no code yet, tho I am about to start working on it and wonder what would be the best way to implement lists sorted in several groups. For example movies sorted by genres and as in that example my items must be able to be in different groups too, like a movie that can be an Action but also a Thriller! :) I am about to start working with SQlite so will it be able to help me in what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: @AleksaPavlovic I thought you already had coded the groups. Considering the number of items, I would just create a `Movie` class with the characteristics you need (`String name; List<Genre> genres;` etc), and store them in an arraylist.